# How to return values from main function in js code created by dart2js

Tags: javascript, dart, dart2js

I have dart code that returns a string when it is ran

```dart
main(){
print("hello");
 return "hello";
}
```

Now i need to call this from js so i used [dart2js](https://dart.dev/tools/dart2js) to convert it to js.

How i call it from a node.js application:

```js
var sudokuLib = require('./sudoku-lib');
console.log(require('./sudoku-lib'));
```

I am aware of the large amount of code created by dart2js and it is not a problem since whenever i run the converted js file or the above js code, hello is being printed in the console. But the problem is that I want the returned value to be stored in a variable in my js code, since i will be using the value in my node application.

Is there any way to do this??

Comment: Why does the function have a `void` type signature if it's supposed to return a string?

Comment: my bad, but even the editted code doesn't work @Pointy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that your  dart code is now js code and runing fine :

For exemple like this sudoku-lib.js :

```
function main() {
    return "Hello"
}

// add the code below
module.exports = { main };
```

in a new js file "file.js" you can simply write :

```
const lib = require("./sudoku-lib");
// store it in result var
const result = lib.main();
console.log(`The result is: ${result}`);
```

Ref [node-modules-import-and-use-functions-from-another-file](https://www.stanleyulili.com/node/node-modules-import-and-use-functions-from-another-file/)